# remove line counter in R

Tags: r

I'm wondering when using R, if there's a way to remove the line counter. 
i.e say I were running `seq(0,10,0.01)` and getting

```
[1]  0.00  0.01  0.02  0.03  0.04  0.05  0.06  0.07  0.08  0.09  0.10  0.11
  [13]  0.12  0.13  0.14  0.15  0.16  0.17  0.18  0.19  0.20  0.21  0.22  0.23
  [25]  0.24  0.25  0.26  0.27  0.28  0.29  0.30  0.31  0.32  0.33  0.34  0.35
  [37]  0.36  0.37  0.38  0.39  0.40  0.41  0.42  0.43  0.44  0.45  0.46  0.47
  [49]  0.48  0.49  0.50  0.51  0.52  0.53  0.54  0.55  0.56  0.57  0.58  0.59
  [61]  0.60  0.61  0.62  0.63  0.64  0.65  0.66  0.67  0.68  0.69  0.70  0.71
  [73]  0.72  0.73  0.74  0.75  0.76  0.77  0.78  0.79  0.80  0.81  0.82  0.83
  [85]  0.84  0.85  0.86  0.87  0.88  0.89  0.90  0.91  0.92  0.93  0.94  0.95
  [97]  0.96  0.97  0.98  0.99  1.00  1.01  1.02  1.03  1.04  1.05  1.06  1.07
 [109]  1.08  1.09  1.10  1.11  1.12  1.13  1.14  1.15  1.16  1.17  1.18  1.19
 [121]  1.20  1.21  1.22  1.23  1.24  1.25  1.26  1.27  1.28  1.29  1.30  1.31
 [133]  1.32  1.33  1.34  1.35  1.36  1.37  1.38  1.39  1.40  1.41  1.42  1.43
 [145]  1.44  1.45  1.46  1.47  1.48  1.49  1.50  1.51  1.52  1.53  1.54  1.55
 [157]  1.56  1.57  1.58  1.59  1.60  1.61  1.62  1.63  1.64  1.65  1.66  1.67
 [169]  1.68  1.69  1.70  1.71  1.72  1.73  1.74  1.75  1.76  1.77  1.78  1.79
 [181]  1.80  1.81  1.82  1.83  1.84  1.85  1.86  1.87  1.88  1.89  1.90  1.91
 [193]  1.92  1.93  1.94  1.95  1.96  1.97  1.98  1.99  2.00  2.01  2.02  2.03
 [205]  2.04  2.05  2.06  2.07  2.08  2.09  2.10  2.11  2.12  2.13  2.14  2.15
 [217]  2.16  2.17  2.18  2.19  2.20  2.21  2.22  2.23  2.24  2.25  2.26  2.27
 [229]  2.28  2.29  2.30  2.31  2.32  2.33  2.34  2.35  2.36  2.37  2.38  2.39
 [241]  2.40  2.41  2.42  2.43  2.44  2.45  2.46  2.47  2.48  2.49  2.50  2.51
 [253]  2.52  2.53  2.54  2.55  2.56  2.57  2.58  2.59  2.60  2.61  2.62  2.63
 [265]  2.64  2.65  2.66  2.67  2.68  2.69  2.70  2.71  2.72  2.73  2.74  2.75
 [277]  2.76  2.77  2.78  2.79  2.80  2.81  2.82  2.83  2.84  2.85  2.86  2.87
 [289]  2.88  2.89  2.90  2.91  2.92  2.93  2.94  2.95  2.96  2.97  2.98  2.99
 [301]  3.00  3.01  3.02  3.03  3.04  3.05  3.06  3.07  3.08  3.09  3.10  3.11
 [313]  3.12  3.13  3.14  3.15  3.16  3.17  3.18  3.19  3.20  3.21  3.22  3.23
 [325]  3.24  3.25  3.26  3.27  3.28  3.29  3.30  3.31  3.32  3.33  3.34  3.35
 [337]  3.36  3.37  3.38  3.39  3.40  3.41  3.42  3.43  3.44  3.45  3.46  3.47
 [349]  3.48  3.49  3.50  3.51  3.52  3.53  3.54  3.55  3.56  3.57  3.58  3.59
 [361]  3.60  3.61  3.62  3.63  3.64  3.65  3.66  3.67  3.68  3.69  3.70  3.71
 [373]  3.72  3.73  3.74  3.75  3.76  3.77  3.78  3.79  3.80  3.81  3.82  3.83
 [385]  3.84  3.85  3.86  3.87  3.88  3.89  3.90  3.91  3.92  3.93  3.94  3.95
 [397]  3.96  3.97  3.98  3.99  4.00  4.01  4.02  4.03  4.04  4.05  4.06  4.07
 [409]  4.08  4.09  4.10  4.11  4.12  4.13  4.14  4.15  4.16  4.17  4.18  4.19
 [421]  4.20  4.21  4.22  4.23  4.24  4.25  4.26  4.27  4.28  4.29  4.30  4.31
 [433]  4.32  4.33  4.34  4.35  4.36  4.37  4.38  4.39  4.40  4.41  4.42  4.43
 [445]  4.44  4.45  4.46  4.47  4.48  4.49  4.50  4.51  4.52  4.53  4.54  4.55
 [457]  4.56  4.57  4.58  4.59  4.60  4.61  4.62  4.63  4.64  4.65  4.66  4.67
 [469]  4.68  4.69  4.70  4.71  4.72  4.73  4.74  4.75  4.76  4.77  4.78  4.79
 [481]  4.80  4.81  4.82  4.83  4.84  4.85  4.86  4.87  4.88  4.89  4.90  4.91
 [493]  4.92  4.93  4.94  4.95  4.96  4.97  4.98  4.99  5.00  5.01  5.02  5.03
 [505]  5.04  5.05  5.06  5.07  5.08  5.09  5.10  5.11  5.12  5.13  5.14  5.15
 [517]  5.16  5.17  5.18  5.19  5.20  5.21  5.22  5.23  5.24  5.25  5.26  5.27
 [529]  5.28  5.29  5.30  5.31  5.32  5.33  5.34  5.35  5.36  5.37  5.38  5.39
 [541]  5.40  5.41  5.42  5.43  5.44  5.45  5.46  5.47  5.48  5.49  5.50  5.51
 [553]  5.52  5.53  5.54  5.55  5.56  5.57  5.58  5.59  5.60  5.61  5.62  5.63
 [565]  5.64  5.65  5.66  5.67  5.68  5.69  5.70  5.71  5.72  5.73  5.74  5.75
 [577]  5.76  5.77  5.78  5.79  5.80  5.81  5.82  5.83  5.84  5.85  5.86  5.87
 [589]  5.88  5.89  5.90  5.91  5.92  5.93  5.94  5.95  5.96  5.97  5.98  5.99
 [601]  6.00  6.01  6.02  6.03  6.04  6.05  6.06  6.07  6.08  6.09  6.10  6.11
 [613]  6.12  6.13  6.14  6.15  6.16  6.17  6.18  6.19  6.20  6.21  6.22  6.23
 [625]  6.24  6.25  6.26  6.27  6.28  6.29  6.30  6.31  6.32  6.33  6.34  6.35
 [637]  6.36  6.37  6.38  6.39  6.40  6.41  6.42  6.43  6.44  6.45  6.46  6.47
 [649]  6.48  6.49  6.50  6.51  6.52  6.53  6.54  6.55  6.56  6.57  6.58  6.59
 [661]  6.60  6.61  6.62  6.63  6.64  6.65  6.66  6.67  6.68  6.69  6.70  6.71
 [673]  6.72  6.73  6.74  6.75  6.76  6.77  6.78  6.79  6.80  6.81  6.82  6.83
 [685]  6.84  6.85  6.86  6.87  6.88  6.89  6.90  6.91  6.92  6.93  6.94  6.95
 [697]  6.96  6.97  6.98  6.99  7.00  7.01  7.02  7.03  7.04  7.05  7.06  7.07
 [709]  7.08  7.09  7.10  7.11  7.12  7.13  7.14  7.15  7.16  7.17  7.18  7.19
 [721]  7.20  7.21  7.22  7.23  7.24  7.25  7.26  7.27  7.28  7.29  7.30  7.31
 [733]  7.32  7.33  7.34  7.35  7.36  7.37  7.38  7.39  7.40  7.41  7.42  7.43
 [745]  7.44  7.45  7.46  7.47  7.48  7.49  7.50  7.51  7.52  7.53  7.54  7.55
 [757]  7.56  7.57  7.58  7.59  7.60  7.61  7.62  7.63  7.64  7.65  7.66  7.67
 [769]  7.68  7.69  7.70  7.71  7.72  7.73  7.74  7.75  7.76  7.77  7.78  7.79
 [781]  7.80  7.81  7.82  7.83  7.84  7.85  7.86  7.87  7.88  7.89  7.90  7.91
 [793]  7.92  7.93  7.94  7.95  7.96  7.97  7.98  7.99  8.00  8.01  8.02  8.03
 [805]  8.04  8.05  8.06  8.07  8.08  8.09  8.10  8.11  8.12  8.13  8.14  8.15
 [817]  8.16  8.17  8.18  8.19  8.20  8.21  8.22  8.23  8.24  8.25  8.26  8.27
 [829]  8.28  8.29  8.30  8.31  8.32  8.33  8.34  8.35  8.36  8.37  8.38  8.39
 [841]  8.40  8.41  8.42  8.43  8.44  8.45  8.46  8.47  8.48  8.49  8.50  8.51
 [853]  8.52  8.53  8.54  8.55  8.56  8.57  8.58  8.59  8.60  8.61  8.62  8.63
 [865]  8.64  8.65  8.66  8.67  8.68  8.69  8.70  8.71  8.72  8.73  8.74  8.75
 [877]  8.76  8.77  8.78  8.79  8.80  8.81  8.82  8.83  8.84  8.85  8.86  8.87
 [889]  8.88  8.89  8.90  8.91  8.92  8.93  8.94  8.95  8.96  8.97  8.98  8.99
 [901]  9.00  9.01  9.02  9.03  9.04  9.05  9.06  9.07  9.08  9.09  9.10  9.11
 [913]  9.12  9.13  9.14  9.15  9.16  9.17  9.18  9.19  9.20  9.21  9.22  9.23
 [925]  9.24  9.25  9.26  9.27  9.28  9.29  9.30  9.31  9.32  9.33  9.34  9.35
 [937]  9.36  9.37  9.38  9.39  9.40  9.41  9.42  9.43  9.44  9.45  9.46  9.47
 [949]  9.48  9.49  9.50  9.51  9.52  9.53  9.54  9.55  9.56  9.57  9.58  9.59
 [961]  9.60  9.61  9.62  9.63  9.64  9.65  9.66  9.67  9.68  9.69  9.70  9.71
 [973]  9.72  9.73  9.74  9.75  9.76  9.77  9.78  9.79  9.80  9.81  9.82  9.83
 [985]  9.84  9.85  9.86  9.87  9.88  9.89  9.90  9.91  9.92  9.93  9.94  9.95
 [997]  9.96  9.97  9.98  9.99 10.00
```

How can I produce the above output without the line counter in square brackets?

Comment: Do you still want the line breaks every 12 numbers? (If you don't need the line breaks `cat(paste(seq(0,10,0.01)))` would work)

Comment: `cat` will give you line breaks every `getOption('width')` characters with `fill=TRUE`.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why?

Comment: -1: No need to post such a big example.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Needed to paste in as input for another program.

Comment: @user1987097 In that case, just print the output to a file properly instead of fiddling with the R user interface. `write.table(yourData, file = 'foo.txt', row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)`

Comment: Also consider `writeClipboard(as.character(seq(0,10,0.01)))` for your specific purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @DavidRobinson suggested, `cat` is what you want. If you need linebreaks, supply `fill=TRUE`.

```
cat(seq(0,10,0.01), fill=TRUE)
```